# How to Laravel 9 DB table + Join with Update

Tags: laravel

I need update key in table catalog and I write query (mysql query is right):

`$sql = "UPDATE data_masters JOIN postes ON data_masters.id_user = postes.id_user SET data_masters.nama = 'tes update', postes.nama = 'tes update' WHERE data_masters.id_tes = 'PT-5501'";`

Comment: You need sql in laravel elequent or ? Kindly Breif

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.